# Association in Use Case diagram have arrow?

Tags: uml, use-case

I research about [association] in use case diagram :
It is a line has not arrow as image:
https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor-association.html
[image]

But i using Rational Rose:
If i draw a [association], it is a line has arrow:
Is it ok?
Association in Use Case diagram have arrow?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @Christophe commented, it's possible that, for historical reasons, the association between *actor* and *uses cases* were represented with arrows at some point in the past. Probably by the hand of Ivar Jacobson itself, maybe by the hand of those pioneers eager in using the modelling language before a  formal specification. [Rational Software could have been one of those "pioneers" and Rational its result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Software#UML_and_RUP). But, who knows?

> In 1995, James Rumbaugh joined the company, and Rational acquired Ivar
>   Jacobson's firm Objectory AB from Ericsson. With Grady Booch already
>   aboard, this brought within one company three of the leading
>   object-oriented software methodologists. These three experts attempted
>   to unify their work. To eliminate the method fragmentation that they
>   concluded was impeding commercial adoption of modeling tools, they
>   developed Unified Modeling Language (UML), which provided a level
>   playing field for all tool vendors. It was this collaboration effort
>   that earned Rumbaugh, Jacobson and Booch the moniker "The Three
>   Amigos" within the software engineering industry. At its 1.0 release,
>   the Unified Modeling Language was contributed to the Object Management
>   Group, which has managed its subsequent development.

That was in 1995. In 1997, these 3 musketeers submitted the very first version of the UML to the [OMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#UML_1.x)

> After the first release a task force was formed to improve the
>   language, which released several minor revisions, 1.3, 1.4, and
>   1.5.
>
> The standards it produced (as well as the original standard) have been
>   noted as being ambiguous and inconsistent.

That could explain why we don't have specifications for [1.1, 1.2](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML). But we have for the first formal revision [1.3](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/1.3) (March 2000). Back then, the association between actor and use cases were notated as

> 3.56.2 Notation
>
> **An association between an actor and a use case is shown as a solid line between the actor and the usecase**. A generalization between actors is shown by a generalization arrow (i.e., a solid line with a closed, hollow arrowhead). The arrowhead points at the more general actor.

<sup>Uml 1.3 formal review [PDF](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/1.3/PDF). Pg. 3-92</sup>

Checking out the latest revision <sup>([2.5.1](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1))</sup> and a quick view to the specification [itself](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) <sup>(pg. 639-646)</sup> looks like it didn't change since then.

So, to the question *Association in Use Case diagram have arrow?* The likely answer is no. However, whether this is important or not, I don't dare to say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Association in UC diagram can be drawn either with or without arrow, both approaches are correct.

If it has an arrow it should point from an initiator of the interaction to an activated element so for an initiating actor the arrow will be from the actor to the use case while for a secondary actor the direction will be opposite, from the UC to the actor.

This is implied from the mere fact that this relationship is simply an association so as such can be unidirectional.

Comment: Not totally sure this interpretation is right in view of the UML specs quote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455496/3723423).  I'd rather bet on some historical usages dating back to older specs (in fact Ivar Jacobson the inventor of UC used to use arrows in his books).  But I'd upvote if your statement was underlined by some authoritative references.

Comment: @Christophe Unfortunately I don't have a copy of official UML exams by OMG (so the organisation that is currently responsible for UML development), but on the exams such arrows are used. Hopefully someone else taking UML exam will second that. As I wrote in my answer, it is never explicitly stated by UML spec though. I'll try to look for some other resources stating that clearly.